# How to perform pivot_wider on a dataframe with multiple names_from columns and multiple values_from columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(code=c("A1","A2","A3","A4","B1","B2","B3","B4"),
                pcode = c("el","el","ng","el","ng","el","el","el"),
                psaved=c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10),
                pcost=c(20,20,30,25,34,25,30,20),
                scode = c("e1","e2","e2","e2","e2","e2","e3","e3"),
                ssaved=c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10),
                scost=c(20,20,30,25,34,25,30,20),
                tcode = c("e2","e3","e1","e1","e3","e3","e2","e1"),
                tsaved=c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10),
                tcost=c(20,20,30,25,34,25,30,20))
```

I want the dataframe to be widened such that the contents in pcode, scode, and tcode columns become separate columns. And their corresponding saved and cost values are in their respective cells. The result should look something like this:

[image: Wider Dataframe]

I tried performing pivot_wider to help me get the a wider dataframe with the variables in pcode, scode, tcode to align with their respective cost and save values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to do this in two steps using `pivot_longer` first, then do a `pivot_wider`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rename(code1 = code) %>%
  pivot_longer(-code1,
    names_to = c("name", ".value"),
    names_pattern = "^(.)(.*)$"
  ) %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = code,
    values_from = c(saved, cost),
    names_glue = c("{code}_{.value}")
  ) %>%
  rename(code = code1)
#> # A tibble: 8 × 11
#>   code  el_saved e1_sa…¹ e2_sa…² e3_sa…³ ng_sa…⁴ el_cost e1_cost e2_cost e3_cost
#>   <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 A1          10      10      10      NA      NA      20      20      20      NA
#> 2 A2          10      NA      10      10      NA      20      NA      20      20
#> 3 A3          NA      10      10      NA      10      NA      30      30      NA
#> 4 A4          10      10      10      NA      NA      25      25      25      NA
#> 5 B1          NA      NA      10      10      10      NA      NA      34      34
#> 6 B2          10      NA      10      10      NA      25      NA      25      25
#> 7 B3          10      NA      10      10      NA      30      NA      30      30
#> 8 B4          10      10      NA      10      NA      20      20      NA      20
#> # … with 1 more variable: ng_cost <dbl>, and abbreviated variable names
#> #   ¹​e1_saved, ²​e2_saved, ³​e3_saved, ⁴​ng_saved
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This works on this data, but does not work on mine. In my dummy data, I had 3 main variables-p,s,&t. But in my main data, I have 4 variables p,s,t,q. So altogether 12 columns instead of the 9 in the dummy data. Does that mean I need to change the code somewhere to make it work in my actual data? Also, why did you change the code variable name to code 1?

Comment: Hm Don't think that 12 or 9 isn't the issue. The code is in general enough to deal with that. Issues might arise depending on the patterns of the column names I used for the pivot_longer step, i.e. `names_pattern = "^(.)(.*)$"`. Perhaps you could add a snippet of your 12 column data to your post? The renaming of `code` is necessary as the pivot_longer step will create a new `code` column.

Comment: Oh, yeah. The renaming of the code is necessary here. I am sorry for creating the confusion. The code works now, but I cannot save it for some reason. The resulting dataframe contains list-cols. As a result, when I try to save it as a csv file it say:   
 Error in write.table(df, file = "result.csv",  : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'. Any advice?

Comment: Hm. The list columns are a result of the pivot_wider step and happens in general if there are multiple rows per `id_col`, i.e. per `code`. One option would be to do `group_by(code) %>% mutate(id = row_number) %>% ungroup() %>% pivot_wider(-c(code, id), ...)`. That should fix the issue. But might not be what you have in mind.

Comment: Thanks. The dataframe is not list anymore, but then like you mentioned, my row numbers tripled, but I wanted the rows number to be identical before and after. I don't know how to proceed. If I could just save this list-file as csv, I could filter out the "Null" cells in excel.